# How should I redo my patio under my deck?

Tags: deck, patio

I have a patio composed of large concrete pavers (roughly 2' x 6') (**edit - more likely sections of poured concrete**) - I would guess it is at least 10 years old if not much older. My second story deck is supported by posts on precast concrete footings which sit on the pavers. I'd like to redo the patio as the pavers are uneven and unappealing. What would be the best approach to redoing the patio without rebuilding the deck? Some potential approaches that have occurred to me:

- Pour a concrete slab over the pavers/sections of concrete slab
- Lay deck tiles over the pavers/sections of concrete slab
- Lay a fresh set of sand and pavers over the existing pavers/sections of concrete slab
- Use temporary posts to support the deck while removing and replacing the pavers/sections of concrete slab

How many of these approaches seem feasible? Are there better ones I haven't thought of?

Comment: Your footings are seriously on top of the pavers? That wouldn't be legal here. Can you attach a photo? Generally, the pavers should be removed, using them as a foundation for anything else is asking for trouble, including a second storey balcony. Where do you live?

Comment: I can probably attach a photo later. It occurs to me that these might not be pavers - it might be poured concrete in several sections which have risen or sunk differently over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a photo of the scene I'd assume that you can put temporary legs in place. I'd install appropriate lumber at a slight angle to just outside of the patio area so that you can work on it unobstructed.

- Use something like a pair of 2x6 boards screwed together in a T configuration. This should give you the strength and stiffness necessary.

Plan view:

```
 _________
|_________|
    | |
    | |
    | |
    |_|
```

- Place large blocks under the posts to prevent them from sinking into the soil.
- Drive large steel or lumber stakes into the ground to anchor the temporary post legs.
- Anchor the tops of the posts to the beams such that they won't slip out. This could involve lapped lumber scabs screwed to the posts and the beam.
- Raise the beam slightly from its original position to allow easier installation of the new posts.
- **Block all access to the deck while the project is underway.** Check the security of the temporary posts frequently. A collapse could kill.

How you repair or replace your patio is your prerogative. That part of the question is off-topic as either too subjective or unclear, given the few details you've provided about your ultimate goal.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer but if you can link to a diagram or something to help me picture how the T configuration would work that would help me implement it better.

Comment: Answer updated. Use one 3" screw every 12-16" to secure them together.